# Blurred video-player border with CSS

Tags: css, blur, video-player

I've got [this page](http://stefanoderossowebdesign.altervista.org/prove_sito_ale/home.html) where I'd like to give to the exterior of the player a blurry effect, something like [this](http://www.cogfilms.com/tutorials/surface-tension/center-border-square.jpg), with the black part being transparent.  
Is it possible to do that only with CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not dependent on external resources. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `box-shadow` instead of a css border

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
```